# QUERY IN C# ,where statement

Tags: c#, .net, select

How can I write this query on c# :

```
SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME=combobox1.text;
```

Comment: what about `SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME=combobox1.text;` What exactly are you asking, it´s quite unclear. Is your question on how to set up a database-Connection and firing a query against it?

Comment: `var query = "SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME=" + combobox1.text;`. I suspect you want more than that though.

Comment: You are probably looking for How to: Create and Execute an SQL Statement that Returns Rows, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fksx3b4f.aspx

Comment: i get this error: quoted string not properly terminated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Assumed that you are using SQL

this a generic query for your question:

```
SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand();
cmd = "SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME= '" + combobox1.Text + "'";
```

here is what I recommend

```
SQLCommand cmd = new SQLCommand();
cmd = "SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME= @comboBox";
cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@comboBox", combobox1.Text);
```

I've used command parameters so that data types is automatically assigned and also helps you against "SQL Injections".

Comment: i get this error :quoted string not properly terminated

Comment: something is wrong with your quotations. I assumed that the error is somewhere near the combobox1.Text. I recommend that you copy the lines of codes I suggested. remember also that don't leave spaces between Single Quote and double quote as it may consider it as another character.

Comment: this is my code : string sqlcommand = "INSERT INTO GROUPS(GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME,DEPT_ID) " +
                              "VALUES(" + MAXID + ",'"
                              + textBox1.Text +
                             "', SELECT DEPT_ID FROM PERSONNEL_TEMP.DEPARTMENT WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME="+comboBox1.Text;

Comment: and it gets this error on OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlcommand, con);
            oda.Fill(dt); :One or more errors occurred during processing of command.